# Comments are abruptly truncated in feed

Tags: bug, ios-app

As per the title, comments which are truncated in the feed end abruptly*:

[image: truncated comments]

There should be an indication that there's actually more text in the comment; the main site uses an ellipsis for this purpose.

<sub>*They also can get truncated mid-word, which the main site is guilty of too, but bonus points if we can have a smarter truncation so you don't have the comment ending on the first letter of the next word</sub>

Comment: Your red dots in the top example are not even aligned vertically. I cannot focus!!!

Comment: Freehand ellipsis!