# Cannot see that a question is closed on the iOS app

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, closed-questions, ios-app

On the iOS app there no indication that a question is closed until you try to answer it and get an error

App version 0.1.17

Comment: [Duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220368/closed-question-status-isnt-indicated-anywhere)? Although it was marked as completed.

Comment: Idk I still cannot see any closed indication

Comment: Is this a case where the question was closed while you were answering it?

Comment: No in general, I cannot see any indication that a question is closed. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: How did you get to the question? The `status-completed` on the linked post was by blocking the questions from being displayed, but I think you can still get to closed qusetions from the inbox

Comment: Huh? I do not see any indication that a question is closed

Comment: There is no indication the question is closed. The "solution" was to prevent display of the question in the first place. But if you get to it by the inbox, you can bypass said "solution"

Comment: We do plan to implement special handling of closed questions, although they have been temporarily removed from search results.

Answer (score 1):

As of version **0.1.26**, we now have handling of closed, locked, and migrated questions. It will look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the new closed status bar]