# Please implement closed question filtering or better indication on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

In a preveious request to have closed questions identified, the [answer states in conclusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220568/165931):

[Closed question status isn't indicated anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220368/closed-question-status-isnt-indicated-anywhere)

**Update**: the next update should exclude closed questions from the questions list.  While we do plan to have more complete support for closed questions in the near-ish future, I consider this to be the fix for this bug.  I've now marked it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

As the answer was posted in Feb 2014, it looks like this fix has regressed or been changed. This filtering and/or indication of closed status isn't happening on v 1.1.0.94 of the iOS app.  You can see by searching for **yosemite** on Ask Different between now and general release of that OS to get a good mix of questions that are on hold and closed. Tapping the question does then show in the footer the correct closed/hold status, but it's not clear from the main list view.

Please either filter closed questions from the list of questions when browsing on a site or indicate their  closed status by pretending the subject line with [hold] or [closed] to clearly indicate their status.

Answer (score 2):

We have added the question status (such as [on hold] or [closed]) to the beta version of the app. It's described in more detail [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240103/232374).

Comment: Also, this question probably should have gotten the answer (it's a bit older), while the other marked as duplicate, but when I answered the other one I wasn't aware of this one.