# Title does not specify "On Hold"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, ios-app, title

Testing the app, I noticed the title does not specify if a question is "On Hold" ... I haven't checked specifically, but would assume it doesn't specify as "Duplicate" either ... Or am I missing it somewhere? Is it not in the title but located/displayed some other way? If it is, this could be very confusing to users. If it isn't there, it's definitely confusing to users :-)

Using: Version 1.0.1.125 on iPad3 with iOS8

Comment: Sorry for the wrong dupe vote, thought the other one was older. (retracted now, but you might still have the comment notification)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... no worries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

I've added the question status under normal question listing. This should show up in beta version **1.2.1.168.**

[image]

However, it's not currently possible to have this show up on search results, because [search excerpts](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/search-excerpt) are much more limited, and do not include things like migration or protection info. Although a partial implementation there *is* possible (since we have data like closed and locked dates), I will defer that portion until we update the API to include the missing data.

---

**Original answer**

All statuses such as  On Hold, Duplicate, Bounties, Closed, Migrated, etc are displayed in the app within the question page with a floating bar on the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Even so, why isn't it displayed in the title on the main list of questions as we'd see it on any of the SE Sites?

Comment: To further clarify my point, yes it says it *after* you open the thread, but there is no way (as far as I can tell) it is marked as on-hold or duplicate prior to opening. Some might say after it's put into this state, it's a moot point to open it. When looking at it in a browser, the reader would see and have that option. In the app, there isn't the choice. Can be confusing.

Comment: @Paulster2 I'd really like this feature on the main menu too! I regularly browse on bad 3G (on trains), and it can be frustrating to wait 10 seconds for a question to open, and then see its closed. Questions with favourite tags are a blue colour, perhaps closed ones could be faded out, or grey or something?)

Comment: Sorry but feature request can't really be "by design". Obviously, that is the current design, **which the OP wants to change** (that's the whole point of a feature request). It can be either done or rejected.

Comment: Ummmmm yeah. I'm 100% with @ShadowWizard here. It ***can't*** be status-by-design. We're asking for a change. Decline it, fine, but this is a serious PITA on mobile. Particularly [on the iPhone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243107/closed-question-indicator), I don't want to load a question only to find out that it's been closed.

Comment: Sorry about that; I've updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, so now it is pending a decision?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yes, I'll be taking a more in-depth look at this, hopefully this week.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ArieLitovsky please keep the phone apps in mind for this. It's a huge problem there. Thanks.

Comment: One minor thing: it's also showing this for protected questions, where it doesn't show in the ordinary site. Nice bonus, but not consistent.

Comment: [poke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250829/title-of-questions-closed-as-duplicate-long-time-ago-does-not-say-duplicate-in) :)