# Closed question indicator

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, ios-app, title

On the regular site, there's an [On Hold] indicator after the title when a question has been closed. It would be nice to have something similar for the iPhone app. It's a bit frustrating to waste time clicking on a question only to realize that it's off topic *after* it loads.

Comment: For what it's worth the situation is the same on the Android app.