# Titles should indicate question status in the iOS app's search results

Tags: feature-request, search, ios-app, api

Question titles in search results show no indication of the post's status (i.e. [duplicate], [on-hold], [closed], [protected], [migrated]... are there any more?).

I spotted this in the search results, for example:

> [image]

Click the question... Oh, it's a duplicate!

> [image]

The same holds for all other post-title-status-indicator-thingies. The site doesn't omit the status from titles in search results so I see no good reason to do so in the app.

---

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240103/307988), this is due to a limitation in the API. The [`search_excerpt`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/search-excerpt) object still doesn't return the post status. Could this be added to the API and added to search result post titles?

---

- App Version: 1.6.3
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I'd blame caching. This is normally indicated but can take a minute to show up, particularly if you haven't refreshed.

Comment: Don't think it's caching, it's been like this for a while (and you can't refresh search results per-se, you can re-do the search of course but that has no effect)

Comment: Actually, just found [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240103/307988), apparently this is due to limitations in the API