# Cannot see which questions have been flagged on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, ios-app

When I have been browsing questions on the Stack Exchange app, I cannot see which posts have been put on hold/migrated, I then end up flagging these posts when in actual fact they have already been flagged.

Is this a feature that could be implemented into the app, or are there technical constraints that prevent this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237377/please-implement-closed-question-filtering-or-better-indication-on-ios-app?rq=1

Comment: There's nothing wrong in flagging a question that already has flags or pending close votes. I agree that something is missing compared to the desktop version, but it's really not a big deal.

Comment: Just to make sure, you mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pKPeH.png), right? If not please explain better what you mean.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that as well, I also mean in the title of the question, on the desktop website it shows the text [on hold] or [migrated] whereas on the app, it does not. There have been a couple of occasions where I have flagged a question and it has already been resolved.

Comment: @AEJBUG it does show it in titles now in the Beta version, see [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240090/title-does-not-specify-on-hold). At some point they will put version in the app store with this as well. As for the pending flags/close votes, it doesn't exist yet indeed.