# Question suffix in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Ya know, there's these [closed] and [on hold] suffix right after the question title in the web version:

> [image: .]
>
> See the [duplicate] text? After the question?

Is it possible to add the same thing to the iOS app? Does this text exist in Android app? If no, can the same request be done to the Android app too?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220368/closed-question-status-isnt-indicated-anywhere